# How to compile CIFilter at runtime?

Tags: cocoa, core-image, runtime-compilation

I would like to do at runtime in a program, what Quartz Composer does with the  Core Image Filter patch:
[Compiling a CIFilter inside Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html). Quartz Composer has a patch that takes the text of the CIFilter kernel, with which it creates the CIFilter.

Do we have access to this in the public API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to [apply a kernel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIFilter/apply%3aarguments%3aoptions%3a), and the kernel is created with the [+ kernelsWithString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIKernel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIKernel/kernelsWithString%3a) class method.